# Software installation - Error : when using command 'make' - make: Fatal error: Command failed for target

Tags: linux, software-installation, compiling, void-linux

**EDITED: (After solved): so guy's, It's seems like the `base-devel` pkg. Which one have include header on it. Now working properly :)**

> Thanks to you guy's (i get this help from a FaceBook Linux-user Group
>   )

I am installing a package at the moment on to my Void Linux x86_64 version 5.4.21_1 and I have run into a problem with the 'make' command. I have installed the package command and I am now at the stage where I have to use the 'make' command followed by the 'make install' command. According to the instructions for the package you just type 'make' and 'make install' and it should compile. When I use the 'make' command I get the following error :

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks .

> This is the full error. GCC is definitely installed. I am running the
>   'make' command from the directory with the makefile in it. And this is
>   not only for st pkg. I have faced this problem with any git
>   installation packages. :(

```
$ git clone https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st
$ cd st 

$ make
st build options:
CFLAGS  = -I/usr/X11R6/include  -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16  -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -DVERSION="0.8.2" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600  -O1
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lX11 -lutil -lXft -lXrender  -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lfreetype
CC      = ”/usr/bin/cc”
”/usr/bin/cc” -I/usr/X11R6/include  `pkg-config --cflags fontconfig`  `pkg-config --cflags freetype2` -DVERSION=\"0.8.2\" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600  -O1 -c x.c
/bin/sh: 1: ”/usr/bin/cc”: not found
make: *** [Makefile:22: x.o] Error 127

$ sudo make install
Password:
c99 -I/usr/X11R6/include  `pkg-config --cflags fontconfig`  `pkg-config --cflags freetype2` -DVERSION=\"0.8.2\" -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600  -O1 -c x.c
x.c:11:10: fatal error: X11/Xatom.h: No such file or directory
   11 | #include <X11/Xatom.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:22: x.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you have X11 headers installed on your system at all? I don't know what the package may be called that has these on your Void Linux system, but on Ubuntu it's called `x11proto-dev`. Also note that you typed `sudo make install` without `make` first (there is no reason run the compile itself as root).

Comment: @Kusalananda   No i don't have **x11proto-dev** on my repo. all i have is **x11perf** and **x11vnc** .  it's a new installed OS. But i used it before and didn't have anykind of problem like this.

Comment: According to the [instructions](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st#user-content-installation-for-newbs) you need `fontconfig`, `libX11` and `libXft`, 
so it's probably `libxft-dev` (search [voidlinux.org/packages](https://voidlinux.org/packages/)). On Debian the `x11proto-core-dev` is an indirect dependency of `libxft-dev`, so that would make sense.

Comment: yes, i do have **fontconfig**, **libX11**, **libXft**, But `libxft-dev` & `x11proto-core-dev` wasn't found in void repo.  Next time when i use it i don't think i have this all installed !  @Freddy

Comment: Using the Void package search there are `fontconfig-devel`, `libX11-devel` and `libXft-devel` packages...

Comment: If you have solved your issue, then you should write that as _an answer_. It's totally ok to self-answer questions.  After you have accepted your own answer (or anybody else's, if there is a better one), the issue will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you don't have the C language headers available for the X11 libraries.  On Linux, the header files are usually not packaged with the actual libraries as  they are never needed to run the programs that uses the libraries.  Instead, they are provided in separate packages.

The software that you are trying to compile depends on the `fontconfig` tool, as well as the `libX11` and `libXft` libraries and the associated header files.  This is according to the software's [`README.md` file](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/st/blob/master/README.md).

The `fontconfig` tool is available as the `fontconfig` package on Void Linux (you may also need `fontconfig-devel`), while the two libraries would be available as the *four* packages `libX11`, `libX11-devel`, `libXft` and `libXft-devel`.  It's the `-devel` packages that you need for the header files.  Once the software has been compiled, these may be uninstalled again (they will at least not be used for this particular task again). The other  packages are needed to run whatever software you compile.

You also don't seem to have `cc` (the C compiler) installed.  This (as well as many other tools used to build software) is provided by the `base-devel` meta package on Void Linux.

As I'm not a Linux user, I can't test these things.